# Navigation over all other content and also content responsive along with the navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I have a navigation that is responsive, although, all seems to work just fine with the navigation. But when it comes to content, the content is not following along with where it should be and that is underneath the navigation. I am not sure how to fix this, but anyways, to see my code go here: http://jsfiddle.net/MsDLC/ and to see the result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/MsDLC/show/

The content in the page is in the div "page" and only has the css:

```
.page{
    margin-top: -400px;
    max-width: 78.667em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Content should be underneath the content? Is that what you meant to write?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say underneath the content, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the code below to `#menu` make the nav go over the text

```
#menu {    
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}
```

Update to answer alignment issue (quick fix)

```
.page {
    max-width: 82.667em; /* this becomes a fixed number */
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 2em; /* spacing for the sides */
}
```

Comment: Which `.nav ul` because there are multiple ones?

Comment: Okay, thanks! As to the code in `.page`, what can I do to where it stays in line with the menu/navigation?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Okay, so on the full screen "version," the text "test" is inline with the navigation. But when you down scale the window's width, the text is no longer in alignment with the navigation header.

Comment: That is because your width is set to "em" which is calculated by font-size. Since your font size is NOT change when the browser window shrinks, the width won't either. Think of it like (78.667 * 15px) = 1180px is your max-width. So you need to change all your widths to be calculated by % or include the text in your .page class in the same div as the nav but I would not recommend that.

Comment: Okay, so I am confused as to what to set my width to?

Comment: I updated my answer to what you should set your `.page` value to. This will work for what you are looking to do. If you want talk about another option let's move this convo to SE chat.